# creating wcf in existing Asp.net MVC project

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, service

I need a guide on how to create a wcf service inside an existing asp.net mvc project ....

I tried myself but getting some troubles and just getting confusing. Anywhere I can get information on this. Really having a hard time finding this on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project in the solution explorer, Add New Item, WCF service..., basically a couple of clicks.

Comment: I know about that .... more specifically how to use it ? it's so different then when creating a separate project..

Comment: @Reza M, what's so different about it? You define your Data Contracts, a Service Contract, implement the Service Contract, define an endpoint in web.config, generate a client proxy and invoke the service.

Comment: how would you invoke the service ?

Comment: @Reza M., you add a service reference and then `using (var client = new MyServiceClient()) { var result = client.SomeServiceMethod(); }`, the same way you would do it in every other .NET client application, pretty standard stuff.

Comment: Alright, that's where i wasn't sure ... I'll try it and report back. Just gonna get a break first.

Comment: @Darin, hey I tried adding the service but kept getting an error on downloading the metadata.... I'm guessing I need to add some info in the web.config ? like the app.config when you create a wcf service project

Comment: @Reza M., in this case you are hosting the WCF service inside an ASP.NET application (which happens to be an ASP.NET MVC application). So you should use web.config to configure your service and client endpoints (because it is the same application hosting and consuming the service). But this doesn't really matter, once you have the WCF service .svc endpoint exposed and are able to query the WSDL metadata you could point the Add Service Reference wizard to this WSDL and it will generate the client.